# File Not Found Error using ImageFolder Class in PyTorch

Tags: python, image, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am getting an error: #FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find any class folder in C:/Users/dylan/Documents/Capstone/Data/book.

I have a capstone folder which has a Model Folder, a Data Folder(inside Data folder is my book folder that has a bunch of photos of books, plant, and chair), and a src folder with my code that is trying to use the images from my Data folder.

So I believe my paths and  everything are fine.  Below is my code.

```
object_types = ['book','plant','chair']
save_dir = 'C:/Users/dylan/Documents/Capstone/Models'
#save_dir = './Models/'

# define generic Transform each photo, resize, flip the image/rotate image
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512,512)),
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=30),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

#need to calculate mean and std for normalize function, creating lists for means and standard deviations
means = []
stds = []

for object_type in object_types:
    dataset = datasets.ImageFolder("C:/Users/dylan/Documents/Capstone/Data/" + object_type, transform=transform)
```

I am not sure why my code is not able to get the images from my book folder.

I tried to use the below to see what was going on, but I was able to print the path of my book folder by printing book_folder_path and I was able to list plant, book, and chair folder directories with the "for f in os.listdir." code snip.

```
for f in os.listdir('C:/Users/dylan/Documents/Capstone/Data/'):
    print(f)
book_folder_path = os.path.join("C:/Users/dylan/Documents/Capstone/Data/", "book")
print(book_folder_path)
```

Comment: I actually think I just solved the problem. I was not allowed to have just the images in my book, plant, and chair object labels for some reason. I needed to make each object type have another folder named images in which I put all my images in. So now my folder is Data/book/images/image1.jpg....etc